# How to remove Content-Disposition from rails render json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to simple return a JSON from a controller.

```rb
# routes.rb
get '/blah', to: 'controller#blah'

# controller

def blah

  render json: { 'blah' => 'blah' }

end
```

When I attempt to make a call to this

```
➜ http localhost:3000/blah
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=pipefy.json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
ETag: W/"b96bdb35152fb257e0085bf459ab0868"
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id: c606ca23-87ac-4ba6-aab3-6d7762e6517f
X-Runtime: 0.127904
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

How can I simple return the JSON, without `Content-Disposition: attachment;`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What headers do you have if you call `localhost:3000/blah.json` ?

Comment: @razvans I find out that there was a middleware that was injecting this header.